# Shared views in ionic framework

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have one template 'song-detail' that I want to access from two other parts of my application. However, I can only use the nav history for the first one.

I want to access 'song-detail' from both the browse nav view, and the favourites nav-view. I can access it fine from both, but I only get the 'back' history from the tabs.browse.

Is it possible to get the nav history when sharing a single 'song-detail' view like this?

```
        .state('tabs', {
            url: '/tab',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
        })

        .state('tabs.browse', {
            url: '/browse',
            views: {
                'tab-browse': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-browse.html',
                    controller: 'BrowseCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('tabs.song-detail', {
            url: '/songs/:song_id',
            views: {
                'tab-browse': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/song-detail.html',
                    controller: 'SongDetailCtrl'
                }
            }
        })


        .state('tabs.fav', {
            url: '/fav',
            views: {
                'tab-fav': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-fav.html',
                    controller: 'FavCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('tabs.fav-detail', {
            url: '/songs/:song_id',
            views: {
                'tab-fav': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/song-detail.html',
                    controller: 'SongDetailCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have missed the abstract state:

```
.state('tab', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})
```

then you'll have the tabs container (**tabs.html**):

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/browse">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-browse"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  ...

</ion-tabs>
```

You have to  change your last state:

```
.state('tabs.fav-detail', {
            url: '/fav/:song_id',
            views: {
                'tab-fav': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/song-detail.html',
                    controller: 'SongDetailCtrl'
                }
    }
})
```

notice the url: `url: '/fav/:song_id'`

and this is your **tab-fav.html**:

Notice you have the link to `href="#/tab/fav/{{song.id}}`.

Everything should work as expected.

Comment: Hi, I have an abstract state that browse and fav are part of. My problem is accessing song-details from more than one view.